# Cygwin return different format of date for `date -u` command

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, cygwin, datetime-format

When I execute `date -u` command from Cygwin Terminal / Cygwin Bash shell, It returns the output `Tue, Jul 14, 2015  2:52:47 PM`

But when i executed `bash` command from command line, then executed `date -u`, it returns the output `Tue Jul 14 14:52:27 UTC 2015`

I need this command to be always return this output format: `Tue Jul 14 14:52:27 UTC 2015 (%a %b %d %H:%M%S %Z %Y)`

Why it return different datetime format? How can I change these to same format?

Path for different Cygwin terminal:

```
Cygwin Terminal: C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
Cygwin Bash shell: C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat
Bash: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
```

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. I don't want to try new options. I need to know & fix why this `bash` alone return different format. In all the Linux terminal, `date -u` return the format: `%a %b %d %H:%M%S %Z %Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format depends on the system's locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=it_IT.utf8 date -u
mar 14 lug 2015, 18.04.18, UTC

$ LC_ALL=POSIX date -u
Tue Jul 14 18:04:29 UTC 2015
```

If you want consistent `date` output, explicitly set your system, user, script or date command to use the `POSIX` locale.

Answer (score 1):

You could just explicitly state the format in your date command.  You basically have the output format assembled already.

date -u +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'